# Can we set values to only for some of the properties in Atomikos JTA properties and get the default values specified in jta.properties for others?

Tags: transactions, jta, atomikos

I want to set value of `com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name` property to `transaction-log` and value of `com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir` property to `/log_dir`. I need to change only these two and get the default values for all other properties in the `jta.properties` file. Can I do this by specifying the above two properties in a `transactions.properties` file and give its path as a system property to `com.atomikos.icatch.file`? Will the default values for the other properties be accessed using the `jta.properties` file if I am not specifying them in my `transactions.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

1. built-in defaults are loaded first
2. properties in transactions.properties are loaded and override 1
3. properties in jta.properties are loaded and override 2
4. properties in a custom "file" override 3
5. JVM properties (System properties) override 4